# A transformation transforms a line to a line, if and only if it is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Given $T(x,y)=(x',y')$ prove that the following two conditions are equvalent:
>
> - T transforms straight lines into straight lines.
> - T is a linear transformation.

The "if" direction is easy. However, I have no clue how to start with the only if direction. Probability I would prove by contradiction by assuming that, if a transformation is not linear, then it transforms line to other things?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that linear transformations transforms lines into lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1804145/how-to-prove-that-linear-transformations-transforms-lines-into-lines)

Comment: Here's a counterexample: $T(x,y)=(x+1,y)$ transforms straight lines into straight lines, but $T$ is not a linear transformation.

Comment: See [my old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1885736/81360).  You will need some more assumptions; at the very least you must assume that $T(0) = 0$.  If we are also given that $T$ is bijective, then this is a consequence of the ["fundamental theorem of projective geometry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation#Fundamental_theorem_of_projective_geometry).

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/107648/81360)

Comment: To flesh out the comment by @Omnomnomnom, some linear transformations map some lines to a point (the origin), so even the easy "if" direction needs "more assumptions".